# Keyboard covering (overlay) input fields in PWA App after last Samsung update

Tags: angular, keyboard, progressive-web-apps, overlay

Since Friday, when users tries to input data in input field, it is hidden by the virtual keyboard.
It was not doing this before.

The problem does not occurs in the browser but only in the PWA App on Samsung. Does not occurs on One+ Nord phone.

Android 11
Version One UI 3.1
Application : Angular PWA
Application manifest information : display : standalone or fullscreen (same problem)
Phone : Samsung (A41 but also occurs on other Samsung devices)

Does anybody has the same problem?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just found the problem! Two images we referenced in the `manifest.json` where not at right sizes!! We had one image which was `383x384` (real size) instead of `384x384` and one other which was `511x512` instead of `512x512`.

Stupid error, stupid loose of time. Seems impossible to lead to this kind of trouble, but it does.

Comment: You really think thats a reason?

Comment: my png was 120120, but after change to 512512 - nothing changed - kb still hides input fields.

Comment: Changing 'display' 2 standalone - solved the problem

Comment: @Monochromie : Yes it was the reason but you also have to set the display in standalone, you are right